# Spring Boot - how to catch java.net.UnknownHostException

Tags: java, spring-boot

we have a Spring Boot Application which runs on a VPN.

It may happens that the outgoing communication goes down for some minutes, so the app cannot connect anymore with the DB, and we get the exception

```
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
.....
.....
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: cxxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com
```

The problem is that the application does not quit in this case (if it quits it restarts on his its after a while) but obviously it's not working.
I would like to know if there is a way to catch this exception, so we could gracefully exit and restart it.

It's a standard Spring Boot application, so we have the typical starting class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class StartServer extends SpringBootServletInitializer{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        SpringApplication.run(StartServer.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Look in the stack trace and then look for a good spot where you could catch this exception and exit gracefully.